# Using pyspark to write to cassandra with timestamp

Tags: python, apache-spark, cassandra, pyspark

I'd like to be able to use Cassandra's `USING TIMESTAMP` like:

```
INSERT INTO ... VALUES ... USING TIMESTAMP 1000;
```

Using pyspark, specifying which timestamp to use. Currently, I'm saving a dataframe value like:

```py
dataframe.write.mode("append").format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(
   **load_options
).save()
```

I have checked the documentation and looked around, but could not find any information about this, if it's possible (and how to do it) or not. Is there a way to have this option in pyspark?

Answer (score 0):

The Dataframe API doesn't support writing with timestamp or TTL - it's available only in the RDD API. It's a common limitation for all languages.

I haven't tried myself, but it looks like that it should be possible via `pyspark-cassandra` package, that have [corresponding options](https://github.com/anguenot/pyspark-cassandra#pysparkrdd).